# How do I install Node Js on my dedicated server

Tags: node.js, centos

I have a dedicated server maintained by GoDaddy. I want to run Node Js on it. Is there any documentation available on how to install Node JS on my server? I have a CentOS dedicated server.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the nodejs configuration from http://nodejs.org/ 
The important thing you need to keep in your mind is about its configuration in file app.js
which consists of port number host and other settings
these are settings working for me

```
backendSettings = {
"scheme":"https / http ",
"host":"Your website url",
"port":49165, //port number 
'sslKeyPath': 'Path for key',
'sslCertPath': 'path for SSL certificate',
'sslCAPath': '',
"resource":"/socket.io",
"baseAuthPath": '/nodejs/',
"publishUrl":"publish",
"serviceKey":"",
"backend":{
"port":443,
"scheme": 'https / http', //whatever is your website scheme
"host":"host name",
"messagePath":"/nodejs/message/"},
"clientsCanWriteToChannels":false,
"clientsCanWriteToClients":false,
"extensions":"",
"debug":false,
"addUserToChannelUrl": 'user/channel/add/:channel/:uid',
"publishMessageToContentChannelUrl": 'content/token/message',
"transports":["websocket",
"flashsocket",
"htmlfile",
"xhr-polling",
"jsonp-polling"],
"jsMinification":true,
"jsEtag":true,
"logLevel":1};
```