# Is Node.js supported on a linux PHP server?

Tags: linux, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Node Js on my dedicated server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049789/how-do-i-install-node-js-on-my-dedicated-server)

Recently I purchase a linux server on GoDaddy. I want to program my site with Node.js.

Is it possible to use Node.JS on my server?

Comment: You need to tell us which Operating System you're using on GoDaddy and whether it is dedicated to determine this. Node.js is compatible with many, not compatible with some. "linux" is insufficient.

Comment: Depends on whether you have a hosting plan that allows you to install anything on the server or not (which is generally limited by hosts to their "Dedicated" or "Private" (virtual machine) plans). If you have this access, find and follow their instructions for running the [appropriate installer](http://nodejs.org/download/) or [package manager command](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager). If you don't have this access, you're limited to whether they'll install it for you or having to change to another plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a cloud instance, then yes, you can do anything. If you just have standard cheap hosting, then I doubt it. Most likely you would need root access to the machine to install the dependencies.

I'm guessing (don't ask me how) that you have the latter. Why don't you ask GoDaddy?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it says to go ask GoDaddy for the answer.

Comment: (1) It does to a good degree of certainty - I once tried to install RoR on a dedicated server, and (2) asking GoDaddy is the best way to get a completely authoritative answer.

Comment: I suppose if your answer said what your comment does, I'd be more inclined to agree.

Comment: Minor details, now please remove your downvote!