# Installing Node, NPM (and then Grunt and Bower globally) in Vagrant

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, bower

I've been following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fideloper/7074502) for installing a bunch of core dependencies for PHP development, but one that I do need and have not been able to get working as of yet is to install Node, NPM (and then Grunt and Bower globally) in Vagrant. I've seen answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049789/how-do-i-install-node-js-on-my-dedicated-server) but it doesn't ever appear to complete the install (ie. I can't then install bower and grunt). There is a `nodejs` package through `apt-get` that does appear to install Node (and I can install NPM from there), but the version appears to be too old for Bower, so that's why I backtracked to a manual approach. Thanks for any help.

## Update

Here is my `bootstraph.sh` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo ">>> Starting Install Script"

# Update
sudo apt-get update

# Install MySQL without prompt
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'

echo ">>> Installing Base Items"

# Install base items
sudo apt-get install -y curl wget build-essential python-software-properties python g++ make

echo ">>> Adding PPA's and Installing Server Items"

# Add repo for latest PHP
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5

# Add NodeJS repository
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js

# Update Again
sudo apt-get update

# Install the Rest
sudo apt-get install -y php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 nodejs php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-xdebug mysql-server

echo ">>> Configuring Server"

# xdebug Config
cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
xdebug.scream=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
EOF

# Apache Config
sudo a2enmod rewrite
curl https://gist.github.com/fideloper/2710970/raw/5d7efd74628a1e3261707056604c99d7747fe37d/vhost.sh > vhost
sudo chmod guo+x vhost
sudo mv vhost /usr/local/bin

# Symlink /var/www to project web root
sudo rm -rf /var/www
sudo ln -s /vagrant/ /var/www

# PHP Config
sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/display_errors = .*/display_errors = On/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

sudo service apache2 restart

echo ">>> Installing NPM, Grunt CLI and Bower"

curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli bower

echo ">>> Installing Composer"

# Composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't then install bower and grunt"? Where does the error come from, and what is it? I suspect you're screwing up your NPM install by getting it both from the repo (chris-lea is usually the latest stable version of node, so that's not the problem) and from a manual run.

Comment: Actually, to add to that, the install.sh from NPM isn't being run as root, which is probably an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the following that works well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "--- Let's get to work. Installing now. ---"

echo "--- Updating packages list ---"
sudo apt-get update

echo "--- MySQL time ---"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'

echo "--- Installing base packages ---"
sudo apt-get install -y vim curl python-software-properties

echo "--- Updating packages list ---"
sudo apt-get update

echo "--- We want the bleeding edge of PHP ---"
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5

echo "--- Updating packages list ---"
sudo apt-get update

echo "--- Installing PHP-specific packages ---"
sudo apt-get install -y php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt mysql-server-5.5 php5-mysql git-core

echo "--- Installing and configuring Xdebug ---"
sudo apt-get install -y php5-xdebug

cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
xdebug.scream=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
EOF

echo "--- Installing node.js ---"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y  python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y  nodejs

echo "--- Installing Ruby ---"
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements
rvm install ruby
rvm use ruby --default
rvm rubygems current

echo "--- Enabling mod-rewrite ---"
sudo a2enmod rewrite

echo "--- Setting document root ---"
sudo rm -rf /var/www
sudo ln -fs /vagrant/public /var/www


echo "--- Turn on errors ---"
sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/display_errors = .*/display_errors = On/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

echo "--- Restarting Apache ---"
sudo service apache2 restart

echo "--- Install Composer (PHP package manager) ---"
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Laravel stuff here, if you want

echo "--- All done, enjoy! :) ---"
```

Source: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Vagrant-Setup

Answer (score 2):

We use [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n) to manage node.js versioning on both our Vagrant VMs and cloud boxes. We are using [Ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/) to manage the installation but it can easily be achieved using bash, something like:

```bash
# Install n
n_directory='/opt/n'
git clone https://github.com/visionmedia/n.git $n_directory
cd $n_directory
make install

# Install node.js/npm using n
node_version='0.10.24'
n $node_version

# Install the global dependencies
npm install -g grunt-cli bower
```

This relies on `n` and `npm` being available on `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks - looks like I can get Node installed using [the first option here](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814), but then installing Grunt-CLI and Bower don't seem to be reading from the root of my site (think the symlinks might be off for some reason). I've updated my original question with my `.sh` file doing the magic. Thanks!